# Android application cannot connect to Mysql server

Tags: android, mysql, json, localhost, remote-access

Im new in android and trying to using my actual device to connect mysql server on my laptop,the url for my virtual device is 10.0.2.2, and it's work.But in my actual device,i set it to 10.1.1.3 (get it by ipconfig),it just keep loading and nothing happens. i have XAMPP server up and running.

I followed this tutorial : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/  and works fine in virtual device.

im using my actual device via wifi and using HTTPpost and json to connect my laptop,both in the same network.Thanks for any help.

Comment: android doesn't have mysql drivers. it cannot talk to a mysql server directly. do you mean your device can't talk to the WEBSERVER?

Comment: try to make sure that your WebServer is Online ( right clic on your WampServer => Put Online )

Comment: i have xampp server and it is running in locahost, how i put it online? im still not familiar about the xamppServer(just contacted it in recent days)

Comment: I would be interested in this answer as well, I tried setting my pc ip in the httppost and it doesn't work return any results as well. Tried accessing the file from my device browser no dice either.